# Automapper error in time of object population

Tags: c#, .net

I have a table in SQL Server with following design:

```
 Name VARCHAR(50)
 Duration TIME(7)
 Status VARCHAR(10)
```

The data in the table is as following:

```
 ABCD_TT 00:00:24:6823454 PASS
```

I have the following DTO in my application:

```
public class Entity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan Duration { get; set; }
    public string Status { get; set; }
}
```

I am using AutoMapper to map data to Objects. Following is the code:

```
IDataReader dr = dataAccess.ExecuteDataReader(sQuery);
lstData = AutoMapperUtil<Entity>.MapObject(dr);
```

I am encountering the following error:

"Invalid attempt to call FieldCount when reader is closed".

What could be the reason of this error ? How I could perform the above mapping?

Answer (score 1):

I've gotten that before when the `dataAccess.ExecuteDataReader()` method inadvertently closes the connection used by the `SqlDataReader` before returning. If that method has `using` blocks for the `SqlConnection` and/or `SqlCommand` objects, then the connection will be closed automatically when the `SqlDataReader` is returned, since it leaves the `using` scope.

There are other possibilities, but it's hard to tell which one it might be without seeing the `ExecuteDataReader` code...

UPDATE: Another common pattern is to close the connection in a `finally` block. That would have the same effect, since the DataReader's underlying connection would be closed by the time it got returned to the calling code. So, check for that too. Or any other explicit call to `.Close()`.